# lambda function or self-defined function

Tags: python, lambda, keras, keras-layer

```
 xa_inp     = Input(shape=branch_model.output_shape[1:])
    xb_inp     = Input(shape=branch_model.output_shape[1:])
    x1         = Lambda(lambda x : x[0]*x[1])([xa_inp, xb_inp])
    x2         = Lambda(lambda x : x[0] + x[1])([xa_inp, xb_inp])
    x3         = Lambda(lambda x : K.abs(x[0] - x[1]))([xa_inp, xb_inp])
    x4         = Lambda(lambda x : K.square(x))(x3)
```

Can anyone help me explain what is the `Lambda(lambda x:)()`      I know the anonymous function lambda, but this is a litte different.

Comment: Where is `Lambda` defined? Is it a class in your code, did you import it from a library?

Comment: I am not sure. This is from someone's kernel on Kaggle:

Comment: the link is: https://www.kaggle.com/martinpiotte/whale-recognition-model-with-score-0-78563

Comment: See the line: `from keras.layers import Activation, Add, BatchNormalization, Concatenate, Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, GlobalMaxPooling2D, Lambda, MaxPooling2D, Reshape` so this is from the `keras.layers` package. I suggest looking at the documentation for that package.

Comment: Got it for thanks!

Comment: @renesmith is your question about what `Lambda` layer does?